# how to print the file names in specific order

Tags: perl, vba, command-prompt

i have file in a location in names order, when i tried to print file names using command promt it print in some other order

below is this command promt code i used print the names

'dir /b,

input files

```
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
```

output i get

```
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
```

output i need

```
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting on first, second, and third number within string (second and third are zero if not found)

```
print my @arr = 
map { $_->[0] }
sort {
  $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] ||
  $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] ||
  $a->[3] <=> $b->[3]
}
map {
  my ($f, @r) = /\d+/g;
  unshift @r, (0) x (2-@r);
  [ $_, $f, @r ];
}
<DATA>;

__DATA__
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
```

output

```
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) to sort a list in natural order.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

print natsort <DATA>;

__DATA__
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
```

Outputs:

```
RU29_SCHEDULE_1_00001.xml
RU29_SCHEDULE_2_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00001.xml
RU29_SECTION_00002.xml
RU29_SECTION_00003.xml
RU29_SECTION_00004.xml
RU29_SECTION_00005.xml
RU29_SECTION_00006.xml
RU29_SECTION_00007.xml
RU29_SECTION_00008.xml
RU29_SECTION_00009.xml
RU29_SECTION_000010.xml
RU29_SECTION_000011.xml
RU29_SECTION_000012.xml
RU29_SECTION_000013.xml
RU29_SECTION_000014.xml
RU29_SECTION_Preamble.xml
```

Comment: hi @mpapec thanks for ur help, as am begginer to perl i dont have much knowledge in sort and map funtion can u plz explain me the code so tat it would be helpful for me to learn. thanks in advance

Comment: For info on [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html), just read perldoc.  For general Perl info, read the [Modern Perl Book](http://modernperlbooks.com/).  It's available free online.